# Force.com Site SSL issue - https://domain.com not working while https://www.domain.com works

Tags: force.com-sites, ssl

I have created a Force.com site and mapped a custom domain to it. SSL is enabled.

The issue is, when I visit the domain with link like this `https://domain.com`, it fails to load anything. Browser shows this error: This site can’t be reached.

The domain works fine for links like below:

https://www.domain.com

domain.com - redirects to the above links

www.domain.com  - redirects to the link at top

http://www.domain.com  -  redirects to the link at top

http://domain.com - redirects to the link at top

What should I do to make this link to work: https://domain.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000113361&language=en_US) in Salesforce. I faced same issue in past and did a workaround as below.

1- Create/buy a Apache instance. Create a **A record** for `domain.com` with Apache instance public IP in DNS. Install SSL certificate (CA Signed) for https://domain.com in the Apache server.

2 - Write a 301 redirect rule in the Apache conf file to redirect from https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am going to implement your suggested approach. Lets see how it works.

Comment: It will definitely work, as I have already tested it. Please let me know if you will stuck anywhere.

Comment: @abdn Nice to hear that i could help you :)