# godaddy provide two file for SSL certificate Which file should I've to upload in salesforce

Tags: ssl

I've Send the SSL certificate to Godaddy for signing.

They send me zipped file of signed certificate. When I opened the Zip file, It contain Two file. Out of those two file which should I've upload to salesforce.

[image]

Or

Should I've to upload both? If yes How?
Below are Two certificate provided by godaddy.

[image]

Comment: This signed certificate is not correct for your Salesforce custom domain. Your Salesforce custom domain is _www.shipperman.us_ and the generated certificated is for _shipperman.us_, both are different domains. You have to re-sign the certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this dev forum [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BQoLIAW). You need to upload a single file that contains the SSL certificate, Intermediate CA Certificate and then the Root CA Certificate in that order.

1.Open a Notepad or any Text Editor.

2.Paste each certificate as per below order.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(SSL certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(CA Intermediate certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Root certificate) 
-----END CERTIFICATE------
```

3.Save the file as ".cer" file. Now upload the newly created ".cer" in Salesforce.

Comment: They provide only two. not three. So should I've put code from two file into one file as per your mentioned order. Correct?

Comment: It seems the  Intermediate CA certificate is missing. All GoDaddy root and intermediate certificates are available at this link. But I don't know which one is correct. You should contact GoDaddy to get the intermediate certificate.

Comment: Thanks I've combined the both certificate into single. and its working fine.

Comment: Can you please help on this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177366/custom-domain-is-not-working-without-www