# DNS A record pointing to site.com website

Tags: site.com

A client has a site.com site and is trying to set up a registered domain's DNS to point at the site.

They have it working with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) via a CNAME (as per the [instructions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.siteforce_domains.htm&type=5)), but they want example.com to work too and I can't see a way to set up an A record to make this happen.

Does site.com offer static IPs? Can I solve this another way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom domain is not working without www](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/177366/custom-domain-is-not-working-without-www)

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385794&type=1) in Salesforce. I have given a solution to this SFSE [Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137926/force-com-site-ssl-issue-https-domain-com-not-working-while-https-www-doma).